# How to dynamically set an array names during the Run time in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Consider we are evaluating some value and based on that we are assigning the name of the array i.e

```
if (Value == 1) {
        set array_name "One"
    } else {
        set array_name "Some_Number"
    }
    type[] array_name;//Set the Array name here
}
```

Can we create dynamic names of array in java ?

Comment: What is the use case? Why would you like to have this?

Comment: You can't. But you can wrap your array and string value ('name')

Comment: I am looking to allocated variable names of Array  during the run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't mentioned the use case, but if you want to assign array a name based on a condition and later want to access the array with the same name, you can use a HashMap.

```
HashMap<String,String[]> arrayMap = new HashMap<>();
if (Value == 1) {
    arrayMap.put("One",youArray);
} else {
        arrayMap.put("some_number",youArray);
}
String[] myArray = arrayMap.get("One");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I hope there is no other way than hash Map

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternative can be;

```
//populate array with whatever name
int[] arrayA = new  int[3];
    for(int i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++) {
        arrayA[i]=i*10;
    }
//copy the previously populated array to the desired name array
if (Value == 1) {
    int[] one = arrayA;
} else {
    int[] some_number = arrayA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Java. Variable names cannot be set or changed dynamically.